# SSDT sqlpackage.exe publish output prints "altering" statements without actually altering the object in the sql script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Has anyone else come across what appears to be a bug in the sql that is generated from sqlpackage.exe publish/generate script?

Basically it generates a lot of PRINT statements like it is altering objects, but the sql to alter those objects is not in the script (though there is other sql for any other expected changes.)

It looks like this:

```
....
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[TableName]...';


GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] DROP COLUMN [ColumnName];

GO
PRINT N'Altering PK_Table1PrimaryKey...';


GO
PRINT N'Altering PK_Table2PrimaryKey...';


GO
PRINT N'Altering UK_Table1UniqueKey...';


GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[TableName].[idx_Index1]...';


GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[stp_1]...';


GO
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_1]
AS
BEGIN
.....
```

So it is mainly with constraints and indexes where there is a PRINT statement without a matching sql statement. I have not seen the issue with stored procedures.

I am unable to find any connect tickets around this, but I have been seeing this behavior with multiple SSDT database projects (VS2012 and 2013).

I'm assuming there is a difference detected in the schema but the publish setting overrides the change (ex. Ignore Fill Factor or FileGroup Placement settings are on). This appears to be a bug where it is suppressing the sql but not the output, which is very misleading when you want to review (or preview) a deployment but the change in the output did not actually occur.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to Google this issue for a while with no luck. Thanks!

Comment: Haven't come across this one, but wondering what your options are for this particular publish? Are you selecting not to push indexes/constraints? Anything else that seems different? Does this also happen if you do a schema compare of the project against the target DB?

Comment: I actually found the cause of it based on this similar experience - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4c34b3b-3369-4a10-85d2-038569ca6446/database-project-setting-ignore-fill-factor-not-working?forum=vstsdb. My publish settings are NOT to ignore fill factor differences. On these particular objects that come up as print statements only, there are no fill factor settings in the project. Schema compare does show the difference. You would think publish would either assume the default setting for these or just leave what is on the server.

Comment: So the workaround is to either just leave the ignore fill factor setting on, which I assume the majority of people must be doing, or to make sure all indexes have them set in the project. But it seems like there should be a connect ticket to fix this bug. If it isn't going to alter them, fine, but don't generate print statements saying it did.

Comment: Good catch, Emily. I think we either have the Fill Factor set in our databases or are ignoring it on publish. I'd say opening a Connect ticket on it is probably worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I have submitted a Connect ticket if anyone would like to up-vote it. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1033961

Comment: Just to add to Emily's response.  I had the same issue and her fix worked for me.  I THINK the reason why is because we had customized fill factors set on some of the indexes, Ignore Fill Factor was unchecked, and there was no fill factor specified in the script.  So it was being detected as a change but no actual script to change it was generated because there was no value specified in the script to change it to (so I assume it was left as-is instead of being reset to the database default).